# Adding a cycle numbre to the name of an object

Tags: java, arrays, object, cycle

I have this code in Java

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            Boton[1][j].setIcon(PeonN);
            Peon PeonNegro = new Peon('N');
            Boton[6][j].setIcon(PeonB);
        }
```

This is for a Chess, I want each new object to have the number of the loop do use it independently without creating an array, to have something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
            {
                Boton[1][j].setIcon(PeonN);
                Peon PeonNegro+i = new Peon('N');
                Boton[6][j].setIcon(PeonB);
            }
```

So I'll have PeonNegro0, PeonNegro1 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to do this without an array or `Collection`. (In Java, it would be quite difficult to use a dynamic variable name). You'll have to declare something like an array or `ArrayList` outside of your for loop, as shown below.

```
Peon[] peons = new Peon[8];
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
{
    Boton[1][j].setIcon(PeonN);
    peons[j] = new Peon('N');
    Boton[6][j].setIcon(PeonB);
}

// So we can access a single peon like this
Peon p3 = peons[3];

// Or iterate over all peons and get the cycle number like this
for (int cycle_num = 0; cycle_num < 8; cycle_num++) {
    Peon peon = peons[cycle_num];

    // Do something with peon and cycle_num here

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to know if It would be possible to do that without an array, I guess I'll have to do it the common way :P

Comment: Yep, common way it is. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That's not how JAVA works. If you want to have a sequential list of variables, your options are to use arrays or one of the `Collection` objects. Variables cannot be named dynamically.

Also, it's worth noting that since you declared that variable inside the `for` loop, the variable will only be accessible until the next iteration of the loop. i.e. you can't even use the variable outside of the loop anyway, so there's no reason to number them.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, to create them and then manipulate them 1 by 1